# UICollectionView Delegate method gets called before cell is instantiated?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview, parse-platform

I am working on implementing a UICollectionView that gets its data from online via Parse. I am loading images into the collection view. The problem that I'm having is that one of the delegate methods for the collection view gets called before the cells have been reloaded.

I have a method that loads the objects in the background into an NSArray. Once they are all done I reload my collection view. From there my delegate method is being called prior to `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath`. My delegate method handles the size of each individual cell so that they can change based on the size of a photo.

That's a problem because the cells need to have images in them in order for me to see what size they are for the delegate method.

My delegate method looks like this:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(NHBalancedFlowLayout *)collectionViewLayout preferredSizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    CustomCollectionViewCell *currentCell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (currentCell) {
        return [currentCell.cellImage.image size];
    }
    return [cellImage size];
}
```

Like I said, This delegate method is being called before `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath`. That is resulting in the local variable 'currentCell' return nil. What could I do so that I can properly set this up so after all of my cells are loaded I call the delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having this same probably with the Parse table view.  You're absolutely right about how parse collection and table views set their dimensions.  The problem can be solved by saving the width and height of the image when you upload it.  This way, you can just grab the dimensions of the image **before** the PFFile image has finished downloading (this usually happens after the collection view is set up).

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyParseImage *image = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGFloat imageHeight = [[image objectForKey:height] floatValue];
    CGFloat imageWidth = [[image objectForKey:width] floatValue];
    CGFloat ratio = self.view.frame.size.width / imageWidth;

    return imageHeight * ratio;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for getting back! How did you save the image dimensions on Parse? Were you able to save it as a CGSize object or did you save the height/width individually?

Comment: Yep I saved the width and height individually as NSNumber objects.  It would like look `[myParseImage setObject:imageWidth forKey:width]` then just save it as usual with `[myParseImage saveInBackground]`.

Comment: I'm actually still having an issue with this. The problem is that in order to retrieve an image from a PFFile you have to load it via a block. Once that block is loaded I have access to the image. From there I can then get the width/height. The problem is that you can't return a value from a block. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added width and height fields to your image class in your parse database?

Comment: Yes I have done that and I can access them, but in order to get those attributes you need to load data in the background with a block. You are not able to return a value from a block, so I can't set the value after I have gotten it.

Comment: I ended up changing my implementation so that I could access that information without needing to load anything. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Jonathan Awesome!  How so? I'm curious.

Comment: Well for my situation I am using a PFQueryTableViewController at the top level. Each cell of that table view has a collectionView, which hold images. So my PFQueryTableViewController receives a PFObject that I need to pass that tableViewCell. From there I take it and query that object to retrieve the images inside. Once I have those objects I saved them into a property on the tableViewCell subclass. I can then directly access the image object's in the preferredSizeAtIndexPath method. I did set it up so that I have width/height as a part of each photo object. I just return the CGSize for those.